# Django Sites Framework on Localhost Based on Port (8001, 8002, 8003)

Tags: python, django, port, sites

I'm developing on localhost, assigning each port (8001, 8002, 8003) to correspond to each site (site1.com, site2.com, site3.com).

How do I get the Django sites framework to recognize these ports as sites, or cause them to correspond?

Comment: How are you running your Django code?  On a ngnix or apache web server or just executing `python manage.py runserver ...`?

Comment: This may help you: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/

Comment: I'm running on Gunicorn nginx. I tried to differentiate them by simply appending the port to each domain name but it seems to default to the same example.com based on 127.0.0.1, ignoring the 8002, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this (on Ubuntu)

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.11.1  site1.local
127.0.12.1  site2.local
127.0.13.1  site3.local
```

Then in Django Sites:

```
site1.local, site1.local
site2.local, site2.local
site3.local, site3.local
```

Then in nginx sites available/enabled

```
server {
    listen 127.0.11.1;
    server_name site1.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on; 
        alias /home/.../static/;
    }
    location /media/ {
        autoindex on; 
        alias /home/.../media/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

Then, KEY POINT, do NOT use SITE_ID variable in settings. 
Then I isolate it with

```
get_current_site(request).domain
```